# C++ Robocopy with userdefined inputs

Tags: c++, windows

I'm a beginner with C++ currently trying to write a little program to help with robocopy backups for network devices, so far I've come up with the below code, but when i try to compile i get the following error:

31 no match for 'operator<<' in '"ROBOCOPY //" << oldname'

I get the same error repeating for all the lines using robocopy, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
      string oldname;
      string newname;
      string userid;  
      char response;        


      cout<<"Please input old device name eg XXXXXX\n";
      cin>> oldname;

      cout<<"Please input new device name eg XXXXXX\n";
      cin>> newname;

      cout<<"Please input userid eg SP12345\n";
      cin>> userid;                  

      cout<<"Does your current device contain a D: drive? Y or N?";
      cin>> response;

                  if (response == 'Y')
                  {

                   std::system("ROBOCOPY //"<<oldname<<"/c$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Desktop //"<<newname<<"/C$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Desktop /MIR /w:0 /r:0");
                   std::system("ROBOCOPY //"<<oldname<<"/c$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Favorites //"<<newname<<"/C$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Favorites /MIR /w:0 /r:0");
                   std::system("ROBOCOPY //"<<oldname<<"/c$/Users/"<<userid<<"/My Documents //"<<newname<<"/C$/Users/"<<userid<<"/My Documents /MIR /w:0 /r:0");
                   std::system("ROBOCOPY //"<<oldname<<"/d$ //"<<newname<<"/C$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Desktop/D backup /MIR /w:0 /r:0";
                       }        

                  else if (response == 'N')
                  {
                       std::system("ROBOCOPY //"<<oldname<<"/c$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Desktop //"<<newname<<"/C$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Desktop /MIR /w:0 /r:0;
                       std::system("ROBOCOPY //"<<oldname<<"/c$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Favorites //"<<newname<<"/C$/Users/"<<userid<<"/Favorites /MIR /w:0 /r:0;
                       std::system("ROBOCOPY //"<<oldname<<"/c$/Users/"<<userid<<"/My Documents //"<<newname<<"/C$/Users/"<<userid<<"/My Documents /MIR /w:0 /r:0;
                       }

                system("pause");          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, this simple statement doesn't work:

```
std::string str;
system(str); //<== expecting C-string
```

Because `system` expects a null-terminated C-string, not `std::string`. You make it worse by adding text:

```
system("text" + str);
```

The compiler doesn't know what to do with that.

Secondly, `system` cannot properly pass command line parameters. You need `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx`

You may also have to pass application's full path. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>

void foo(std::string userid, std::string oldname, std::string newname)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss  << "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Full Path\\Robocopy.exe" 
        << " /c:\\users\\" << userid << "\\Desktop\\" << oldname 
        << " /c:\\users\\" << userid << "\\Desktop\\" << newname
        << " /MIR /w:0 /r:0";

    std::string commandLine = ss.str();

    //examine the commandline!
    std::cout << commandLine << "\n";

    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

    char *buf = _strdup(commandLine.c_str());
    CreateProcessA(0, buf, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    free(buf);
}

int main()
{
    foo("x", "y", "z");
    return 0;
}
```